# Running Nativescript app as a desktop app on Windows

Tags: nativescript

Is it possible to somehow run nativescript app as a desktop app on Windows? I'm also interested if there is a possibility to use Windows API in the app (for example to create a file).

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible, since you can't build a {NS} project for desktop.

However, Windows 10 will add a support of running Android apps on desktop (codename Project Latte).